# (Angular, Openlayer) Is it possible to import classes from an external package inside a ng library to ng app

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, gis, openlayers

I'm currently working an angular library that sets up an openlayers map that can be imported as an Angular component. The component works fine, but in my angular app that runs the component, I need access to some classes / constants that live inside of one of the packages that the library imports. (Specifically OpenLayers)

**My current work-around is to also have the same package installed inside of the app.** However, there seems to be some form of conversion problematics between the two packages. (Both use's the same version of the package) It's kind of hard to explain the problem in pure text, so I'll provide some psuedo code to explain it further.

In my angular library I have the following method:

```
import { Feature} from "ol";
....

public addFeature(feature: Feature) {
    this.layer.getSource().addFeature(feature);
}
```

And in my angular app I have the following lines of code

```
import { Feature} from "ol";

public test() {
    const feature = new Feature();
    myLibService.addFeature(feature)
}
```

But when I run this, I get the following error:
`Argument of type 'Feature' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Feature'. Types of property 'on' are incompatible.`

This problem is solved by changing the type of `Feature` in the libraries function "addFeature" to type `any` which is something I really want to avoid. When creating a new Feature() inside my library everything works fine.

**What I want**
The dream scenario is: Inside my angluar app, I want to be able to import "Feature" from the package "ol" that is installed inside of my-lib. Is something like this possible?

Etc:
`import { Feature} from 'my-lib/node_modules/ol';`

If anything was unclear, or if you need further information about anything feel free to ask away. The provided code is entirely psuedo-code, but should provide the same information as the real one.

Thanks in advance!

I have tried to install the package "ol" (OpenLayers) inside both my angular app, and my angular library. Both uses the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem today. The solution was to add openLayers as a peerDependency in my angular library, and install it as usual in the app that consumes the library.

```
"peerDependencies": {
"@types/proj4": "^2.5.2",
"@types/ol": "^6.5.3",
"ol": "^7.2.3-dev.1676300784989",
"proj4": "^2.8.0" }
```